# Hibernate @OneToMany mapped by 2 different columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an object called **Lecture** and it has 2 fields which are both of type **Teacher**

```
class Lecture{

    private Teacher teacher;
    private Teacher subsTeacher;

}
```

Lets assume a Teacher may teach many lectures. So there is a one to many relation between Teacher -> Lecture

Now in Teacher class I have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
@Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH, 
                            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})
public Set<Lecture> getLectures() {
    return lectures;
}
```

However, this will not return me the Lectures the teacher is subsTeacher to. But I need them as well.

How can I achieve this?

**Table structure:**

Table: Lecture

Columns: id, teacher_id, substeacher_id

Table Teacher:

Columns: id, name

Comment: Issue is only teacher object mapped to lecture set. can you post your table structure please.

Comment: @ambarox I have added the table structure.

Comment: For this you need to filter lectures according to teacher/subteacher and manually set to the lectures list. Otherwise you need to do separate mapping. if you need to save the lectures with the teacher you should add separate mapping and use accordingly.

Comment: @ambarox What do you mean seperate mapping?

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subsTeacher", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Lecture> sublectures;

Use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you need to filter lectures according to teacher/subteacher and manually set to the lectures list. Otherwise you need to do separate mapping. if you need to save the lectures with the teacher you should add separate mapping and use accordingly.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subsTeacher", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) 
private Set<Lecture> subLectures;
```